# Responsividade em iphone

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout-responsivo

Desenvolvi com meus colegas um tema em *Wordpress* que está bem legal em vários dispositivos, porém o rapaz que vai receber o site utiliza um iPhone 5 e neste smartphone as figuras ficaram "esticadas".
Procurei vários problemas relacionados a `meta tag` ou `viewport`, e nenhuma solucionou.
Alguém consegue me dar uma luz sobre responsividade em iPhone?

Link do site: http://www.ufsm.br/arco

Segue código:

```css
content{
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 520px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content2{
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content .resume{
 max-width: 318px;
 }
.content h2{
 max-width: 318px;
}
.content2 .resume{
 max-width: 318px;
 }
.content2 h2{
 max-width: 318px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px){
    .content, .content2{
        float: left;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
    .content, .content2{
        float: none;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }
}
.categoryBox{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.categoryBox span {
    margin-right:10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important ;
}
.categoryBox2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.categoryBox2 span {
    margin-right:10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important   ;
}
.categoryBox a{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #D22800;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "LatoBlack";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.categoryBox2 a{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "LatoBlack";
    background-color: #7DBEA0;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a class="featuredImage" href="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR"><img width="679" height="444" src="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR" sizes="(max-width: 679px) 100vw, 679px"></a>
    <div class="categoryBox"> 
        <a href="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR"><span class="fa fa-book"> </span>CULTURA</a>
    </div>
  <h2><a href="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR" rel="bookmark" title="Abrir Da Itália para Santa Maria">Da Itália para Santa Maria</a></h2>
 <div class="resume">
  <a href="AQUI VAI LINK, NÃO TENHO PONTOS PARA POSTAR" rel="bookmark" title="Abrir Da Itália para Santa Maria">
        <p>Andrea Roberto, vencedor do Concurso Internacional “José Tomás”, realiza concerto na UFSM</p>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Eis o HTML e CSS responsável pela parte que estou me referindo.
No iPhone parece que ele aperta a imagem para caber.

[image: Imagem iPhone 5]
[image: Imagem de outro celular]

Comment: Seria interessante você postar pelo menos um print, o código html e o css do problema que está tendo, se não fica difícil analisar.

Comment: Poste um print de como as figuras ficam normal e de como aparecem no iPhone, bem como a parte do código HTML/CSS disso. Eu desenvolvo sites responsivos e acho que já tive esse problema com iPhone, só que precisaria ver o código pra lembrar o que pode ser. Pode ser problema de compatibilidade do navegador, que renderiza alguns códigos com um pouco de diferença de outros.

Comment: Vê se um `style` `object-fit: cover;` na `<img />` resolve teu problema

Answer (score 0):

As suas imagens de destaque (`.featuredImage img`) tem uma altura e uma largura fixa (esta é apenas uma das duas ocorrências que encontrei no seu código):

```
.featuredImage img{
    height: 222px;
    width: 318px;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
```

O que, essencialmente, invalida toda a ideia por trás da responsividade. Qualquer imagem que naturalmente não tenha essa proporção (aproximadamente 0,69 neste caso), realmente vai "se apertar" para se adequar à essas dimensões, causando a distorção. Removendo a diretiva `height` você já percebe que isso deixa de acontecer.

Recomendo ainda ir mais longe e fazer

```
.featuredImage img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

para que a imagem se adeque ao seu *container*, mas nunca ultrapasse suas dimensões naturais. Deixaria também o `margin-bottom` a cargo do *container* da imagem (no seu caso, o *bootstrap* deve se encarregar disso).

Comment: Essas medidas foram especificadas pelo pessoal da revista, temos que mantê-las, entendo essa parte da responsividade, mas como está nas imagens que upei, o que acontece, e acontece apenas no iPhone, é que ele aperta as imagens, mesmo com tamanho definido. Se comparar com a outra imagem, nota-se que isso não acontece. O que eu queria saber é se o iPhone trata px diferente de outros smartphones.